# How to replace accented characters by their HTML representation

Tags: c#, html, diacritics

I would like to transform strings like "rég" to "gr&eacute;gou".

I temporarily wrote some code that manually changes the most common accents, but I would like to get one that transforms each accent to its html equivalent.

Someone has an idea? :)

ps: I tried something but it does not work ...

C # code:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyEncode(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string text)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Byte[] bArray;


    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text);

    bArray = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(850).GetBytes(text); 

    String chaine = "";


    for(int i=0; i<bArray.Length; i++)
    {
        chaine = chaine + (char)bArray[i];
    }

    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(chaine);
    builder.Append(chaine);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString());
}
```

--OLD

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! At the moment, this site is meant for english-language questions only - can you translate? (Via Google translate: Bienvenue à Stack Overflow! À l'heure actuelle, ce site est destiné aux questions de langue anglaise seulement - pouvez-vous traduire?)

Comment: I've replaced the text with a google-translated English version. Original version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6291316/1).

Comment: I manually improved the translation a little (with all the due respect for Google's tranlator)

Comment: Why do you want to entity encode them? Just use UTF-8 and leave the characters unencoded. Nowadays you usually encode characters with special meaning in html like `<` `>` `"` `'` `&` but not accented characters.

Comment: I did!! but is doesn't working

Answer (score 2):

The [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx) does not modify the argument (strings in C# are immutable!); it returns the encoded version as a new string:

```
string encoded = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("rég");
```

The preferred way to encode text in the context of MVC seems to be the [Html.Encode Helper Method](http://HtmlHelper.Encode%20Method%20%28String%29):

```
<%= Html.Encode("rég") %>
```

Comment: With Html.encode, sometime i get the "é" and some time i don't!

Comment: Yes .. this is the problem we are seeing. We dont want to encode UTF8 accents.. they are fine.. just the dodgey hyper text - not sure why this is

Answer (score 2):

The library [HelperSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/HelperSharp) has a method for this purpose: [EscapeAccentsToHtmlEntities](https://github.com/giacomelli/HelperSharp/blob/master/HelperSharp/StringExtensions.cs#L200)

```
// The result will be: gr&eacute;gou
var escaped = "grégou".EscapeAccentsToHtmlEntities();
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick google search for "HTML entity encode C#" brings up lots of hits ... like the following:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/htmlencodingcsharp.aspx

There are also framework classes that perform this function:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx